# Can't remove an item from an array Vuex

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

Having tried all the methods that I found here (including `this.$delete`), I cannot remove an item from the array.

`findIndex` and `IndexOf` return -1, apparently therefore do not work.
`filter` or `splice` doesn't work either.

I suspect that I am doing something wrong.
I will be grateful for the help

Vuex

```
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    coefficients: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    getDataState(state, coefficients) {
      state.coefficients = coefficients;
    },
    itemDelete(state, item) {
      const index = state.coefficients.findIndex((el) => el.id === item.id);
      if (index > -1) state.coefficients.splice(index, 1);
      // #2 state.coefficients.splice(index, 1);
      // #3 
      /* const index = state.coefficients.indexOf(item);
      console.log(index, 'index');
      if (index > -1) {
        state.coefficients.splice(index, 1);
      } */
    },
  },
  actions: {
      getData({ commit }, userData) {
      api.get('/coefficients/')
        .then((res) => {
          commit('getDataState', {
            coefficients: res,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, 'error');
          commit('error');
        });
    },
      deleteData({ commit }, { id, item }) {
      api.delete(`/coefficients/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
          commit('itemDelete', {
            item,
          });
          console.log(res, 'res');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, 'error');
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Component

```
        <div v-for="(item, index) in this.rate.coefficients" :key="item.id">
          <div>{{ item.model }}</div>
          <div>{{ item.collection }}</div>
          <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
          <span v-on:click="deleteItem(item.id, item)">X</span>
         </div>
         
        /* ... */

         methods: {
          deleteItem(id, item) {
            this.$store.dispatch('rate/deleteData', { id, item });
            },
        },
         created() {
          this.$store.dispatch('rate/getData');
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `itemDelete` mutation expects an object with an `id` property, but you are passing it an object with an `item` property, because you are wrapping `item` in a plain object while passing it.

Change the commit in `deleteData` to pass the item without wrapping it first:

```js
commit('itemDelete', item);
```